# Vector Math question

Tags: vector, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two game object located at two Vector3s v1 and v2, respectively.
If I wanted to locate a position between v1 ad v2, but 3 units away from v2, how would I manage that in terms of calculating the target vector (vT)?  Basically, I want object 1 to translate toward object2, so that it can play an attack animation a reasonable distance away from the combat target without being on top of it.

I calculate a vector pointing from v2 to v1:

```
Vector3 heading = v1 - v2;
Vector3 headingNorm = heading.Normalize();
```

From there, how to I "add 3 units in the direction of v1 from v2" to get the target position?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give your question or more meaningful title, e.g. "How to find a specific point between two others?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vector3 vT = v2 + headingNorm * 3;

Be careful though, if v2 and v1 happen to be closer than 3 units away this will put you on the far side of v1.  Maybe you want this to make the unit step back to make room for the attack.  But then again be careful, because that means as you approach that attack point you will overshoot then correct and overshoot the otherway over and over again!